# Facebook Comment (fb:comment) returning httpS content when called over http?

Tags: facebook, http, https, comments

This just came up ~10 days ago:

I have a page that's 100% http.  But, the facebook javascript (which I call over http), is returning assets (.js, images) over HTTPS, which is generating security warnings for IE(9) users.

I have figured out it's the comment widget from Facebook (

Here's an example of a live page on 100% http: with the error:
    http://app.gophoto.com/p?id=10173&rkey=CD01891B287792415384&s=1&a=6940

Here's one of the assets that Facebook returns over HTTPS
    https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/y8/r/7Htnnss1mJY.js

How can I get facebook comments to come back to the page as http? 
Or, truly, are all 3rd party websites that use fb:comments going to need to be displayed over https 100%?

Comment: this is likely a bug, you can file it here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs https support is a requirement for canvas apps and page tabs, not for external sites.

Comment: I filed a bug w/ Facebook here:  http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/174276242655775   Not sure what the track record is, but I'll keep watch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  Right above your FB.init function, just put FB._https = true;

That did it for me and the security wanrings is gone for IE9.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work.  I tried FB._https=false; (which makes more sense for my specific problem), as well as FB._https=true;  Neither solved the problem.  The page is still 100% http UNTIL the facebook comment plugin returns https assets & breaks it.